# Issues with TFS Aggregator implementation

Tags: tfs

We used TFS Aggregator to automatic update the User Story's state according to its sons state changes and also to automatic Update User Story's state of other project (if they are related). 
Also important to mention that we hire an external freelance to help us doing it. When we tested it on his environment - it worked well. But when deploy it in 
our environment - there's no change, the new functionality doesn't work.

what you recommend us to check ?

what can be the reasons for this integration problem?

What actions should we take?

Your advises are more than welcome!

Comment: Why don't you consult with the external freelance you hired? Doesn't he provide the steps how to deploy? Is your environment the same as his? Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: He is trying to solve this but so far we didn't find a solution. We both use the same version ( TFS update 3). Now we are trying to match our environments- for example we We didn't install Visual studio in our TFS server and he did. Our expert says that the aggregator fail to connect to TFS server due to version upgrading issues (we upgraded from 2013 to 2015.3)

Answer (score 0):

First, try to follow the steps of installation on this website to install the plugin: https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/wiki/Install

If it still doesn't work. Here is the troubleshooting page you can refer to: [TFS Aggregator Troubleshooting](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/wiki/Troubleshooting):

- You are using the right version of this server side plugin for the
  right server. You can get multiple releases of this plugin at website
  https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator
- You have updated a work item that triggers a rule. (The TFS
  Aggregation only works once a work item that has aggregation rules on
  it is updated. This may change in a future version.)
- If the rule navigates between work items, work items have a proper
  Link (e.g. Parent-Child).
- You copied the DLLs and the Policies file to the plugins location on
  all TFS Application Tier Servers (Usually at: :\Program
  Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server {version}\Application Tier\Web
  Services\bin\Plugins)
- You have valid names for source and destination fields in
  `TFSAggregator2.ServerPlugin.policies`.
- When you saved the file you saved it as UTF-8 encoding (in Notepad++
  it is called “utf-8 without BOM”).
- You have given permission to the user running the plugin, e.g. add
  the "TFS Service Account" to the Project Collection Administrators
  TFS Group.

  You may have to do this from the commandline using tfssecurity
  /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /g+ "Project
  Collection administrators" "LOCAL SERVICE" if your service account is
  either LocalService, NetworkService or any other Windows Well-known
  identity, since they are no longer shown in the permission UI.
- When using the Impersonation option, make sure the user executing the
  plugin (generally the TFS Service account) has the "Make requests on
  behalf of others" permission at the server level
- If you upgraded your TFS from 2013.x to 2015.* and from 2015rtm to
  2015.1 and did not uninstall the TFS Aggregator before doing this TFS upgrade the aggregator does not work. Remove the TFS Aggregator from
  the TFS 2013 Program Files folder or run the uninstall of the TFS
  Aggegrator (backup your policies!). Then re-install the TFS
  Aggegrator setup or install manually for TFS 2015 as described here.
  Every TFS version has its "own" assembly for the aggregator so it is
  important to use the right version against the right TFS.